# Jquery Plugin - Error Message in popup window for all elements

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jquery plugin - validation.

It is working perfectly but i need to modify as per client's requirement.

Is there any option to show all the errors of each and every element that are highlighted in popup alert box rather than that shown next to individual elements.

Comments will be helpful.

Regards.

Comment: Check out the `showErrors` callback, pretty sure it gives you a list of the errors which you could write our in alert box's.

Comment: thank you for the reply...but i have searched for the code...there is only appending of labels in the form that displays errors. These labels can easily changed to some other tags...but i couldn't show the errors in the popup window.